# To transfer a .ipa file into iPad by using windows machine

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4, sup

I am very much new to iOS development.I am working in native iOS development with Objective C as front end  and SUP 2.1.3 as backend.I have successfully deployed an application in iPad by connecting it to MAC machine.(I am having a valid provisioning certificate.)

Now,I have to deploy my application using the ipa file.The steps that I followed are given below,

1.Product--->archive
2.selected archived file--->distribute---->save for enterprise distribution--->selected the code identity---->saved to a folder
3.dragged the ipa file into iTunes and synced..

This worked properly.

I tried the same procedure  in my windows machine by downloading iTunes .And I connected the iPad to my Windows machine.But it didnt work.Can anyone please help me in solving this?Do I need to add the provisioning certificate or anything like that to my iTunes?I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and iPad 5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to to deploy & test the ipa file on your ipad then follow the instructions as specified here:

[Testing Your App on Many Devices and iOS Versions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375-CH5-SW1)

you do not need to pay the developer fees until you are publishing to the appstore. cheers!!!

Comment: :Thank you aarn.Shall I ask you one more doubt?Actually my iPad's UDID has been got registered in my provisioning certificate.I want to run my application in that iPAD itself using the same provisioning profile.I dont have a distribution profile and am having only a developer profile.Is that possible?It is just for a testing.Sorry I am not so familiar with this technology.

Comment: you can add your ipad's UDID to the developer portal & regenerate the provisioning profile. Secondly deploy it for adhoc instead of enterprise. Check the link which I've given you it has complete steps on how to deploy the app on ipad for testing, go through every sections & follow each step. Also you can upvote the answer if you find it helpful :P

Comment: I understood the details about distribution profile and adhoc distribution.1 more question.Really sorry for disturbing you.Can I do the same using iTunes in my windows machine.If it is possible,do I need to add my provisioning certificate to iTunes in my windows?Actually that was my question..:)

Comment: @RahulPR yes you can do the same using itunes in windows, you need to drag & drop the provisioning certificate on the itunes & then add your ipa file... Good Luck :)

Comment: Hi aarn,I got a distribution profile.And Can I run my application in an iPad which is not registered with this provisioning profile,ie its UDID has nit been got registered with the certificate?Can I get it run on that iPad with that .ipa file only?or I have to use send that provisioning certificate also?Please reply me

Answer (score 2):

Use testFlight OR hockyapp instead of windows System. That is best option for you.

« http://hockeyapp.net

« https://testflightapp.com

Comment: Thank You.Actually my iPad's UDID has been got registered in my provisioning certificate.I want to run my application in that iPAD itself using the same provisioning profile.I dont have a distribution profile and am having only a developer profile.Is that possible?It is just for a testing.Sorry I am not so familiar with this technology.

Comment: yes, Its possible...development profile is for that purpose only. It works when you add UDID in same profile. Use mac system Or test flight/hockeyapp..its free :)

Comment: Guru:Sorry for disturbing u again ,My question was,Can I do the same using iTunes in my windows machine.If it is possible,do I need to add my provisioning certificate to iTunes in my windows?I understood the details about distribution profile and adhoc distribution.

Comment: @H2CO3:Then please answer my question.

Comment: @RahulPR I don't use any of the official distribution methods, I can't really answer it.